# keras inceptionv3 pre-trained model convert to sequential model?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a inceptionv3 pre-trained model, I want to convert this functional model to sequential model. But an error has occured. I don't know why. How can I do this?

```
model_inceptionv3_conv = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
for layer in model_inceptionv3_conv.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = model_inceptionv3_conv.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
predictions = Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid', name='predictions')(x)
my_model = Model(inputs=model_inceptionv3_conv.input, outputs=predictions)

seq = Sequential(model.layers)
```

error

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_7: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 192 but got shape (None, None, None, 64)

Comment: Why do you want to convert to Sequential? Inception models do not have a sequential structure, so it is not possible to do such conversion.

Comment: If it can't do this, I think about other ways. thank you very much.

Comment: If you don't tell us what is the real problem, then we cannot really help you.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know where the real problem is. there is a new problem. I have a inception model as mentioned above. Now, I wan't the model can receive a new input placeholder and then use sess.run() to get the output. I do this x =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 299, 299,
                                          3))，pred = model(x), sess.run(pred, feed_dict{x:x_val}. Is that right?